# Web App not working on Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7, web-server, web-hosting, amazon-web-services

I think I am having an issue with security on Windows Server. I have a web app that I put on a Windows 2008 Server. I first tried it in Development Server and on my Windows 7 machine and it worked fine. Once I moved this app, a web service that was being called fine before does not work. I assume that I have some outbound set to not allow call from happening. I am not a server guy, I am a bit lost.

Edit: I also trying turning off as much as the security settings as possible.

Comment: Joe, what are the details behind "does not work". Are you getting an ASP.NET application unavailable message? What is the HTTP response you are getting? Do you get any response at all? Did you check the event logs for clues? In particular I would look at your application event log and the system event log.

Comment: @Somantra I am running the application fine and I submit a call to the web service and nothing happens. No errors, no system coming to a halt. Nothing. I have checked all the logs and nothings seems amiss. I just can not use this web service. there are 4 that call different web services and none of them work.

Comment: OK, you should probably drop down to the HTTP level to see what the server is actually doing. How are you calling the web service? Do you have an HTTP client where you can see the response code and data? That would be what I would try next.

Comment: @Somantra I have a API call in my program that submits an XML/SOAP request. I am looking at the HTTP log and it does not really show that there is a problem there is a lot code 200's.

Comment: So that does sound like the failed request never makes it to the server if you don't see anything but 200's there. Are you accessing locally? Many of the security settings which are involved here are related to HOW you access the resource. So if you you were accessing this via a localhost URL (that works) then move to production and it no longer works, it may be the bindings of the site in IIS. See if you can access locally from the server and also check the bindings of the site in IIS Manager.

Comment: Other possibilities to rule out would be DEP, UAC and other installation problems. I would scour the event logs to look for clues along these lines. Here is an article explaining the UAC logs: http://sourcedaddy.com/windows-7/other-uac-event-logs.html and here is a Technet article that explains more of how UAC works: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc709691(WS.10).aspx Also Try netstat -noab and see if you can confirm that the server is listening like you think it is. Something simple like a localhost binding will be evident in the output. Trace back from there to the source of prob

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that the clock on the host was 12 hours behind the client and for some reason when the clock was change it worked fine. I don't know why this would be the case, but now I know how to prevent it.